# C++ Win32 API: Force Right Align

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, localization, window

I am trying to have texts in a window/dialog aligned to the right with Win32 API (no MFC).

I see in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) that **WS_EX_RIGHT** only takes effect when **the shell language** is Hebrew or Arabic.

First of all, what is "the shell language" referring to? Is it the system's language?

More importantly, is there a way to force texts to align to the right even when they are not Hebrew or Arabic? Even though I am displaying Arabic texts which are retrieved from resource files using *LoadString()*, the API has no way of knowing these texts are Arabic, to the program, those are just "strings", right?

Does this mean that changing the "shell language" is the only option I have if I want to align my texts to the right?

Comment: Standard Edit and RichEdit controls have an `ES_RIGHT` style for aligning text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. But from the documentation, it says "Using the WS_EX_RIGHT style for static or edit controls has the same effect as using the SS_RIGHT or ES_RIGHT style, respectively." Doesn't this mean that ES_RIGHT, too, will be ignored when using non-Arabic shell language?

Comment: The documentation for [Edit Control Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles) does not mention such restriction, so it will not be ignored.

Comment: And WS_RIGHT is about right-to-left reading order, not right-alignment of text. And I would actually be interested if that comment about it only applying to certain windows editions is actually still applicable now that windows is so much more capable so far as NLS is concerned.

Comment: Thank you @heapunderrun . Even so, what I wanted is for a ListBox to have right aligned style, instead of an Edit box. I couldn't find any style specifically for ListBox, something like LS_RIGHT doesn't seem to exist... I am using ListBox_AddString() to add strings to ListBox and want them to align to the right.

Comment: I don't think the ListBox control supports right-aligned text natively. You would have to create an `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` ListBox and render the text to fit your needs. Or use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-control-reference) control instead. It supports specifying the text alignment for each column. Well, except for the first column, that's always left-aligned. The workaround is to insert a zero-width column at index 0.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable , interesting approach, I will look into it if I'm out of options.

Answer (score 0):

`right-aligned` layout is for languages that are written right to left. If the language does not support right-to-left reading order, the Right-Align properties will be ignored.

As far as I'm concerned, you need to create an Owner-Drawn listbox to draw the items right-aligned as you want. And then you could draw the text for each item by processing the `WM_DRAWITEM message`.

You could refer to the sample: [How to Create an Owner-Drawn List Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-owner-drawn-list-box)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if I can set language for a particular window? Or the entire application? Is there such function in win32 API?